# How does one obtain the Windows installation date, without using WMI?

Tags: c++, winapi

Not much to say about this question...

Comment: Trivia: WMI is that piece of software that can find exactly the information you want when you don't want to use WMI. And nobody *ever* knows how WMI manages to fetch that piece of information.

Comment: Unfortunately I need the information to be accurate when the WMI service is broken -- hence the problem. :( EDIT: And for almost everything else from the Win32_OperatingSystem I was able to get the associated information without WMI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's stored in the registry under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` in the `InstallDate` key. The value is an integer number of seconds since 1/1/1970 (i.e. "Unix" time)

Comment: Is this a documented key (part of API), or an implemenation detail ? The registry is an unfortunate mix of both.

Comment: Good question... I don't know the answer to that one :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "value" (I did use "value" in the next sentence at least :)